# How to calculate the number of trials needed to calculate a probability within a certain error range and certainty?

Tags: probability, statistics

Given an unknown probability distribution, you are trying to estimate the actual probability of a specific outcome happening (which has a probability greater than 0 and less than 100) by doing a number of trials. You have a desired range of error you want to calculate the probability within, E. I believe the correct way to do this is:
(|Calculated Probability - Actual Probability | / Actual Probability)
If it isn’t, let me know.

You want to calculate within range, E, C% of the time, the certainty that your calculated value is within E, your desired range of error. For example, a C value of 75% means that 75% of the time, your % error is less than or equal to your desired error range, E. **How would you calculate N, the minimum number of trials to reach your desired value of C**

If there is a formula for this, please let me know, and if you can’t tell, this is my first time here so please provide feedback. I hope the question that I am asking makes sense.

Comment: Probabilities are from $0$ to $1$ (percentages go up to $100\%$ but can cause confusion).  Your relative error $\frac{|\text{estimated probability} -  \text{actual probability}|}{\text{actual probability}}$ is going to cause difficulties if the actual probability is small, so you might prefer to look at the absolute error $|\text{estimated probability} -  \text{actual probability}|$